# Print variable with backslashes in dash

Tags: shell, echo, printf, dash

My shell is dash. My problem is the following:

```
# A="abc\nde fg"
# printf "$A"
abc
de fg#

# B="abc\\nde fg"
# printf "$B"
abc
de fg#

# C="abc\\\nde fg"
# printf "$C"
abc\nde fg#
```

The string variable I'm working with has both spaces and `\n` and possibly other whitespace characters. I would like to access the variable `$A` without escaping the `\n` in the string. Using single quotes would not interpret it as a variable and using double quotes interprets those special characters.

Does dash have a way built in to the shell to do so? I know I can send the variable to an external program that will double the backslashes for the escape characters in the string, but that just feels wrong.

### EDIT:

I realize my mistake with `printf` but it's unrelated in this case. Initially I was using `echo`. This is a better example of what I'm asking. Here are two of the exact same command sequences, only the first is in bash and the second is in dash:

#### bash

```
$ cat sample.txt
abc\nde fg

some string

$ A=`cat sample.txt`
$ echo "$A"
abc\nde fg

some string
$
```

#### dash

```
$ cat sample.txt
abc\nde fg

some string

$ A=`cat sample.txt`
$ echo "$A"
abc
de fg

some string
$
```

I would like to know if I can have dash not interpret the `\n` in this sequence of commands. I have already implemented a workaround using an external command. The proper use of `printf` does what I want, but I'm curious to see if the dash shell itself has some way of doing this its own.

Here's the reason the question came up, for completeness. I need to read a file and CONDITIONALLY comment or uncomment the bottom part. The first part has a literal `\n` (not newline) that needs to stay that way in the rewritten file.

I split the file into 2 pieces using sed enclosed in backticks and assign those to variables. At the end I concatenate the variables by simply doing something like `"$VAR1$VAR2"`, where `$VAR2` has already been conditionally commented, uncommented, or left alone.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What you posted as “my problem” is just a bunch of text with no explanation. If you have a string in a variable `A` then you can use `"$A"` to get the value of that variable. A variable expansion inside double quotes does not interpret special characters. If that doesn't do what you want then the problem is in a part that you haven't told us about.

Comment: @Gilles have edited the question with more detail

Comment: Your problem is that the two implementations of `echo` behave differently.  If you don't like dash's `echo`, perhaps `/bin/echo` is more to your taste?

Comment: @TobySpeight this is what I was missing. I didn't realize dash had its own implementation of echo. even after doing a "which echo" in both shells they returned the same thing, so I figured they were calling the same program

Comment: `type echo` is what tells you it's a builtin command (though you still have to realise that it's two different builtins).  `which echo` will *always* search the path and doesn't know about shell builtins.

Comment: Now the question is reopened, I'll write that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that Bash and Dash both have `echo` as a builtin, but the two implementations do not behave the same when given a string containing `\`:

```
echo 'abc\ndef'
```

This produces different results on the two shells.

---

You can get consistent output by using `printf '%s\n'`; although this is also a builtin, it produces the same output on both shells (this is not true of all conversions, e.g. bash provides a `%q` conversion which dash does not):

```
printf '%s\n' 'abc\ndef'
```

This produces `abc\ndef` in both shells.

---

You could alternatively use an external implementation of `echo`; on Linux, `coreutils` gives you GNU echo in `/bin/echo`:

```
/bin/echo 'abc\ndef'
```

Note, however, that this is less portable.  The GNU info file has this to say:

> POSIX does not require support for any options, and says that the
>   behavior of `echo` is implementation-defined if any string contains a
>   backslash or if the first argument is `-n`.  Portable programs can use
>   the `printf` command if they need to omit trailing newlines or output
>   control characters or backslashes.

Comment: `printf` is portable to all POSIX systems (an all but some truly ancient Unix systems). `/bin/echo` is not.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are many variants of `echo`. `echo` is not a portable command.

`dash`'s `echo` is actually one of the few `echo` implementations that is UNIX compliant (in that regard at least; `dash` being not multi-byte aware, there are other areas where it's not compliant on systems that support multi-byte locales for instance).

The UNIX specification requires

```
echo '\n'
```

to output two newline characters and

```
echo -e x
```

to output `-e x<newline>`.

While some other shells like AT&T `ksh`, `bash`, `yash` or `zsh` have settings to alter the behaviour of their `echo` builtin (the behaviour of the GNU `echo` command can also be affected by the environment), it's currently not the case for `dash`.

In any case, you don't want to use `echo` to output arbitrary data. The standard and portable command for that is `printf`.

You can find more details including how to implement a different `echo` as a wrapper function around `printf` at in the answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](/q/65803)

Answer (score 2):

You're using `printf` with your variable as the formatting string instead of it being a value interpolated by the formatting string.

Either use `echo` or use `printf` the way it was intended. Here are some examples:

```
A="abc\nde fg" B="abc\\nde fg" C="abc\\\nde fg"
echo "$A"
abc\nde fg

echo "$B"
abc\nde fg

echo "$C"
abc\\nde fg

printf "%s\n" "$A"
abc\nde fg

printf "Here is variable B: %s\n" "$B"
Here is variable B: abc\nde fg

printf "> %s <\n" "$C"
> abc\\nde fg <
```

Incidentally, by using double quoted strings they are parsed and the backslash character `\` is processed. If you define the variables with single quoted strings the entire set of `\` characters can also be preserved:

```
A='abc\nde fg' B='abc\\nde fg' C='abc\\\nde fg'

echo "$A"
abc\nde fg

echo "$B"
abc\\nde fg

echo "$C"
abc\\\nde fg
```

Comment: Thank you. Proper use of printf does print what I want, but is not related to my true question. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @JoshuaMarshall In dash, the `echo` builtin also expands backslashes. Whether `echo` expands backslashes or not depends on the shell (and for some shells on global options or flags passed to echo). Use `printf %s "$A"` to print the value of a variable literally.

Comment: @Gilles this is exactly what I was missing, though it's not in an answer. I'm new to stackexchange and I don't know how I should resolve this. now that I've edited my question, should the answer be edited before I upvote?

Comment: @JoshuaMarshall you can always upvote any question or answer that you find helpful. I'm not sure what else you would want from me here, though.